# Creating a dictionary with comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a dictionary of directory's which pass a certain condition. It's important that each directory is set as a value, and that each key is numbered starting from 1.

I have written something here which does just that, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this?

```
dict(enumerate(sorted([x for x in os.listdir("T:\\") if certain_condition(x)]), start=1))
```

result:

```
{1: 'folderA', 2: 'folderB', 3: 'folderC', 4: 'folderD', 5: 'folderE', 6: 'folderF'}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why not use a list instead? List indices start from 0 but you can just add a `None` first value..

Comment: And your code looks otherwise correct; what is wrong with the resulting output?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the result, I was just wondering if there was a more pythonic way of doing this. Let's say for example I wanted the Keys to be something else like "A","B","C" etc, the enumerate would not work, obviously. what would be the solution then?

Comment: This question belongs on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a list instead:

```
[None] + sorted([x for x in os.listdir("T:\\") if certain_condition(x)]
```

You can access each value by index, starting at 1.

If your keys were not just sequential integers and / or you need to remove items from this without altering indices, a dict comprehension would work too:

```
{'A{}'.format(i + 1): v for i, v in enumerate(sorted(x for x in os.listdir("T:\\") if certain_condition(x)))}
```

or you could use a [`itertools.count()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to provide the counter for you:

```
from itertools import count
index = count(1)

{'A{}'.format(next(index)): v for v in sorted(os.listdir("T:\\") if certain_condition(v)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Martijn, the reason I have to create a dictionary is because this will eventually be passed off to a separate program, which will not accept a list data format

Comment: @iGwok: If it is a function that only uses indexing it'll not notice the difference. `dictionary[1]` and `listobject[1]` will return the exact same value.